# Finding EventHandler for specific event.topic

Tags: osgi, aem

I'm discovering AEM workflows and the flow of the Request for Approval model. I've noticed (confirmed on [AEM docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/publishing-pages.html)) that "if the user does not have the required privileges for publishing a specific page a workflow will be triggered to notify the appropriate person of your request to publish".

Trying to find how it's triggered I've found out `ReplicationProcess` that handles the activation action and sends a `com/day/cq/wcm/workflow/req/for/activation` event. Here is where I get lost - none of the AEM OSGi console known to me covers this relationship.

How can I find the event handler that is used for handling a specific event topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the event topic you can use bundleContext to find reference to proper EventHandler OSGi service, e.g. using AEM Groovy Console :

```
ServiceReference[] sr = bundleContext.getServiceReferences(org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler.class, "(event.topics=com/day/cq/wcm/workflow/req/for/activation)")

for (i=0; i< sr.length; i++) {
    println bundleContext.getService(sr[i])
}
```

> Output
>
> > com.day.cq.wcm.workflow.impl.WcmWorkflowServiceImpl@618c5804

You can also use OSGi Felix Web Console (services tab) to find it:

[image: web console service tab]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for!